# Google indexing other pages before index?

Tags: search, seo

I'm building a site for my sister and I've ran into a problem with the SEO. I've setup the robots correctly and I'm using the correct meta tags for the site but the problem is when someone types in our brand name "Vintetro" our returns page is the highest ranking page and my index page is nowhere to be seen! The link to our site is : http://vintetro.co.uk
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been bugging me for ages now!

Comment: Having not searched for the site before and so not getting personalised search results, I see the site return at the end of the page. Twitter, facebook, soundcloud etc above it. You either have a penalty or you need to do some marketing of the site to get some links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, no penalty has been introduced.

First, there could be many reasons for this, especially since the domain was only registered 2 months ago + it's been recently indexed. However, I suspect after analysing the sites content it is for keyword density reasons rather than anything you as a web developer / designer would have introduced.

On the returns page, the target keyword **vintetro** shows up 10 times. Whereas on the homepage it shows up once, and that is in the footer's copyright message (Not including meta / title tags etc). This is a concept in SEO and natural language processing called [keyword density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_density).

**URL:** http://www.vintetro.co.uk/

- **keyword:** vintetro
- **Count:** 5
- **Density:** 3.82%

**URL:** http://www.vintetro.co.uk/pages/returns

- **keyword:** vintetro
- **Count:** 13
- **Density:** 3.19%

Notice how you have the word over 2 times as much in the returns page embedded in more text? I recommend you look further into [SEO for Shopify](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/general/search-engine-optimization).

A couple of things you could do to potentially improve your situation is:

1. Introduce `<h1>Vintetro</h1>` into the home page
2. Strip out some unneeded content from your returns page.
3. Chill. New websites take months, sometimes years to rank. Looking into [offsite SEO strategies](http://moz.com/ugc/21offpage-seo-strategies-to-build-your-online-reputation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It seems silly that, that is all it was! I've been messing with meta tags, meta descriptions, getting click throughs and everything! Our h1 tag is an img with alt "vintetro" though? Is that not good enough? Cheers again

Comment: Hey @MikeSenior - good question! But no. This does not seem to have the same weighting. I highly recommend appropriately using header tags throughout all your pages. Headings are part of the semantic mark up of the document, whereas alt tags describe the image. Check this out: http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/how-to-use-heading-tags-for-seo/

Comment: If the down voter could please leave a reason for a down vote that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all your help mate, I would upvote you but I don't have 15rep yet! :( Cheers again